# What is Mappable and Non-mappable Memeory

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, memory-mapping

I'm tracing through some sample code and I've run into a function ([ID3D11DeviceContext::UpdateSubresource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/ff476486(v=vs.85).aspx)) by which "The CPU copies data from memory to a subresource created in ***non-mappable memory***."

Physically and/or logically, what are the simplified definitions of *mappable memory*?

Likewise, what are the simplified definitions of *non-mappable memory*?

I've found a lot of detailed (from a beginner's perspective) information on the topic of memory maps and I've added that to my reading list. I've read some basic information that explains what and why memory maps are. As one site put it, "The arrangement of the files on a computer's memory is preserved in a virtual file known as the memory map."

I'm having trouble connecting those definitions and concepts to the terms mappable/non-mappable memory.

I get by with a little help from my friends.

Comment: It is memory you can't address yourself.  Stored on the video card, only the GPU can address it.  You need to ignore that wisegeek.com article, it is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I hope that with enough reading on my part, I can understand _why_ the [wisegeek](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-memory-map.htm) article  is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Mappable memory is what you can access directly from your program through the virtual memory mapping.

If your graphic card's memory is not memory mapped you need to somehow give the card orders to load it from your address space to its address space. Which involves copying.

If the card's memory was shared or mapped, the CPU could write to the shared memory directly thus avoiding unneeded copying.

Answer (score 1):

For graphics, there's basically four kinds of memory:

- **Dedicated video memory:** This is memory that can only be used by the graphics card as it is physically located on the graphics part itself. The GPU can access it, the CPU cannot. The value `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC.DedicatedVideoMemory` is the amount of this kind of memory.
- **Dedicated system memory:** In the case of an integrated graphics part, a portion of main system memory is taken at boot time for dedicated graphics use. The CPU is blocked from accessing it, and it is used solely by the GPU. `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC.DedicatedSystemMemory` is the amount of this kind of memory.
- **Shared system memory:** This is normal main memory that is placed in a mode that both the GPU and the CPU can access. Typically this is accomplished through something like the PCIe memory aperture. `DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC.SharedSystemMemory` is the amount of this kind of memory.
- The **remainder of the system memory** is not accessible by the GPU, only the CPU. GPUs can't typically address more than 4 GB total memory between all three types.

So for a discrete graphics part, `DedicatedVideoMemory` is something like 1 GB, `SharedSystemMemory` is something like 256 MB or greater, and `DedicatedSystemMemory` is 0.

For a integrated part, `DedicatedVideoMemory` is some small number (16 MB or 32 MB) or even 0, `DedicatedSystemMemory` is 256 MB or 512 MB, and `SharedSystemMemory` is 256 MB or greater.

There are also "Unified Memory Architecture" systems such as the Xbox One where there's a small amount of `DedicatedVideoMemory` and essentially all of main memory is also `SharedSystemMemory`.

"Mappable" memory is referring to the shared system memory. If the associated resource is `DEFAULT` then you can't map it because it is allowed to reside in the dedicated video memory. A `DYNAMIC` resource is placed into the shared system memory. A `STAGING` resource is allocated in the 'remainder of system memory' portion.

See the [DirectX Video Memory](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/DirectX-Video-Memory-ee7d8319) sample.

Answer (score 0):

**Memory Mapping** is a term referring the assigning of memory addresses to *something*.  That something can be things like hardware registers for a USB interface or locations in a file.

A *memory mapped file* is a file that can be accessed as if it were in memory, like a huge array.  Some Operating Systems provide functionality for this, on other platforms, the programmer has to model this behavior.

Be aware that the RTOS usually controls access to memory locations, including those that are memory mapped.  Just because *something* is memory mapped (like an I2C port), doesn't mean your User space program can access it directly.